# Does library import keyword "show" improve performance?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm all about making the code as efficient as it can be in both runtime performance and app size. At the moment I'm writing a package which depends on some other package from which I only use 1 class.

Would using keyword "show" improve performance or size anyhow or will the compiler remove unused classes when building apk?

```
import 'dart:async' show Stream;
import 'dart:convert' show json;
```

Comment: The compiler does tree-shaking that should remove unused code.  Additionally, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185291/does-using-show-when-importing-a-dart-library-have-any-benefits-other-than-int