# Is using the show combinator or absolute path a better option for importing a Dart package with a large number of exports in a Flutter monorepo?

Tags: flutter, dart, monorepo

We are using a monorepo structure in our Flutter app which contains multiple packages for each feature domain to separate our use cases and improve distributed work.

Our most used package is called common and contains all of the commonly used entities, components as well as some external dependencies that are used throughout the whole application. It exports a lot of files through nested barrel files so in total there should be 500+ files exported from this package.

Often times we import our common package just to access a single entity. We rarely access more than a handful of entities or services from common. I feel like this approach is getting quite messy while our application grows and our common package has to export more and more files.

After researching a bit I was wondering how to reduce build times. Is exporting a lot of technically "unused" files a good idea?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185291/does-using-show-when-importing-a-dart-library-have-any-benefits-other-than-int) there is no real performance benefit between simply using a library file that exports all of its members or using the show combinator. As far as I understand the show combinator and using an absolute path is not the same so what the better option in this use case? I didn't find any documentation on this.

Since we are using build_runner for code generation which is slow in general we would be interested in speeding things up a bit. Besides that VSCode Intellisense is having a hard time suggesting all of the available classes.